Multiple context menu entries for some extensions
I'm facing some strange behaviours in chrome. Let me show the screenshot:

This isn't default behavour, sometimes occurs. Mostly for OneTab extension but sometimes other happens for other extensions too. What is the main reason of this and how can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Why negative vote? ISn't this a technical question?

Did you find a solution to this? I have the same problem with OneTab on firefox (mac)

Probably I found. Remove and reinstall the extension. Don't forget to export your data for import later.  I did this and problem gone in macos chrome.

It worked, you should add it as a community answer to this question.

@Pylinux I did, please thumbs up and commant. Thx.

Probably I found. Remove and reinstall the extension. Don't forget to export your data for import later. I did this and problem gone in macos chrome.
